# Can you style an element with JavaScript without adding a style attribute?

Tags: javascript, css

When you write `element.style = "..."` in JavaScript in adds the `style` attribute to the element you add the style to. Is there a way to add a style without the `style` attribute, without any libraries?

Comment: You can add a class and then just let CSS do its job styling the element.

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info). What are you trying to do, and why isn't setting the style attribute worthwhile?

Comment: As Heretic said, you might want to explain your end result, because though you *can* do what you're asking, right now it seems like you're trying to perform an unnecessary hack.

Comment: @HereticMonkey in fairness, setting the style attribute either workd *for now* or leads to problems later in my experience. The very high weight the styles have usually mean that if you ever need to apply some common style to something with a `style` attribute you cannot. A 5 minutes job of just adding some CSS turns into a two day task of changing the JS appropriately, testing to make sure there aren't any styles overriding the desired style and amending those (if any).

Comment: I did not want as many style attributes because it could get long and cluttered for others to read. That's all.

Comment: @VLAZ Sure, but as you said in your first comment, why not just use a stylesheet? This seems like a question in search of problem. My comment was more to elicit the reason for the question, to head off answers like the ones below. Granted, most people don't read the comments... but then most people answer duplicates ;).

Comment: @HereticMonkey "*why not use a stylesheet?*" good question. In my experience, it's usually something like 1. there is a task to make some error text red 2. some developer does `.css("color", "red")` because they've picked up an easy task and aren't web developers. 3. some new requirement comes in to add some other styling to error texts (e.g., make them different colour). So instead of just changing what should have been `.errorText { color: red; }` - a trivial CSS change, it's now much more involved.

Answer (score 2):

If you can come up with a selector that targets the element, another option is to append a stylesheet that contains that selector:

```js
const styleTag = document.head.appendChild(document.createElement('style'));
styleTag.textContent = 'div { color: blue; }';
```

```html
<div>Some div</div>
```

It'd be more reliable if you're permitted to change the element in some way, like add a class or other attribute:

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div');
const className = `_${('' + Math.random()).slice(2)}`;
div.classList.add(className);
const styleTag = document.head.appendChild(document.createElement('style'));
styleTag.textContent = `.${className} { color: blue; }`;
```

```html
<div>Some div</div>
```

Comment: Can you remove the style element afterwards?

Comment: By removing the style tag. `styleTag.remove()`

Comment: Why is this preferable over just creating a stylesheet and using a `link` to reference it, then adding/removing the class on the element?

Comment: @HereticMonkey If the style to be applied isn't dynamic, and you have the ability to write and link to external stylesheets, and changing attributes of the element is OK, then yes, that'd be a lot easier, but I didn't want to assume anything given the weird nature of the question

Answer (score 0):

- Add a CSS class inside `styles` tags
- Use the `DOMContentLoaded` event to add a class to the element when the document is loaded
- Get the elment through its tag name
- Use `setAttribute` method in vanillaJS to add the CSS class to your tag elment
- In this way it could be more maintainable yoru code, because you change at css level and JS auntomaticly will put the value tanken from css class declared

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>Example</title>
      <style>
        .styles {
          color: red;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>Hello there</p>
    <script>
      let paragraph = document.querySelector("p")
      
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
        paragraph.setAttribute("class", "styles")
      })
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Isn't it document.addEventListener?

Comment: @RRJudah Sorry my bad

Comment: @RRJudah Actually, it works both with `window` and `document`...

Answer (score 0):

With JS, you can write anything to the DOM, including a `<style>` tag. So for example:

```js
const el = document.getElementById('changeColor');
el.onclick = function(e) { 
   const s = document.createElement('style');
   s.innerHTML = '.box { background-color: yellow; }';
   document.querySelector('body').appendChild(s);
}
```

```css
.box {
   width: 150px;
   height: 150px;
   background-color: red;
   color: white;
   padding: 20px;
}

#changeColor {
   margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
   <button type="button" id="changeColor">Change It</button>
   <div class="box">This is a box</div>
</body>
```